# python - transposing row and column

Tags: python, matrix, transpose

This is my code. I am new to programming, so can you help me solve on how to transpose the row and the column properly?

```
def scytale_encrypt(plain_text, key):

    chars = [c for c in plain_text if c not in (' ',',','.','?','!',':',';',"'")]
    chunks = math.ceil(len(chars)/ float(key))
    inters, i, j = [], 1, 1
    cipher, k = [], 0
    item=[]

    while i <= chunks :
        inters.append(tuple(chars[j-1:(j + key)-1]))
        i += 1
        j += key


    while k < key:
        l = 0
        while l < chunks:
            if k >= len(inters[l])and plain_text.islower():
                cipher.append('z')
            elif k >= len(inters[l]):
                     cipher.append('Z')
            else:
                cipher.append(inters[l][k])
            l += 1
        k += 1
    print (inters)
    return ''.join(cipher);
```

my input 
 [My inpputed plain text and key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRXnD.png)

Comment: looks overcomplicated, post your `plain_text`

Comment: I did upload a pic kindly take a look. I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Here is code & output:

```
aMyArray = [ ['a1', 'a2','a3','a4','a5'], ['b1','b2','b3'], ['c1','c2','c3']]

aMyArrayTrsp = []
aMyArrayTemp = []

sRec = ""
iMaxRows = 0
iMaxCols = 0

print "initial array:"
for i in range(len(aMyArray)):
        sRec = ""
        for j in range(len(aMyArray[i])):
                sRec = sRec+","+aMyArray[i][j]
        print sRec

print "Finding max"
iMaxCols = len(aMyArray)
for i in range(len(aMyArray)):
        if(iMaxRows<len(aMyArray[i])):
                iMaxRows = len(aMyArray[i])
print("Max rows="+str(iMaxRows))
print("Max cols="+str(iMaxCols))

print "Creating a blank 2D list.."
for i in range( iMaxRows ):
        aMyArrayTemp = []
        for j in range(iMaxCols ):
                aMyArrayTemp.append("")
        aMyArrayTrsp.append(aMyArrayTemp)

print "transposing.."
for i in range( iMaxRows ):
        for j in range(iMaxCols):
                try:
                        aMyArrayTrsp[i][j]=aMyArray[j][i]
                except IndexError:
                        aMyArrayTrsp[i][j]=""


print "Final output:"
for i in range(len(aMyArrayTrsp)):
        sRec = ""
        for j in range(len(aMyArrayTrsp[i])):
                sRec = sRec+","+aMyArrayTrsp[i][j]
        print sRec
```

Here is the Output.

```
initial array:
,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
,b1,b2,b3
,c1,c2,c3
Finding max
Max rows=5
Max cols=3
Creating a blank 2D list..
transposing..
Final output:
,a1,b1,c1
,a2,b2,c2
,a3,b3,c3
,a4,,
,a5,,
```